# How to display regions in Google Geomap Visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to display continents with GeoMaps.  It says it can be done here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#regionsexample

But I can't figure out how to have, say, all of Africa be one color without going through each individual African country and assigning it a value.

Any help?

Comment: I don't think this is possible... I played with it a bit, but looks like setting the region to '002' in the data array doesn't work.  Seems like a bug to me

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is ambiguous here as it uses the term "region" to refer to two distinct concepts: the first is the map to display and the second is the area of the map to assign data to.  The GeoCharts include maps of the continents, but not maps with the continents as valid data points.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for continent-level data, or you can build custom maps with the continents as data points ([this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/KVGu--jjUpk) over on the Google Visualization API discussion group documents one example of how to make custom maps).